# Python,cant import from module that imported

Tags: pygame

So I'm trying to import from Proj.py to LaserSprite.py.I want to import Proj to Lasersprite,but Im already importing lasersprite to Proj.

I'm getting this error.
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/aaaaaaaaa Project/Python Project/src/Proj.py", line 8, in 
    from LaserSprite import Laser
  File "I:/aaaaaaaaa Project/Python Project/src\LaserSprite.py", line 2, in 
    from Proj import PlayerShip
  File "I:/aaaaaaaaa Project/Python Project/src\Proj.py", line 8, in 
    from LaserSprite import Laser
ImportError: cannot import name Laser*

**LaserSprite.py**

```
import pygame
from Proj import PlayerShip
pygame.mixer.init()
```

**Proj.py**

```
import pygame
import random
import math
from Vector_Calc import Vector
from LaserSprite import Laser
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `import loop` problem. You can't import A to B and B to A.
This is often a signal that you should redesign your modules layout and their dependencies.

Nevertheless, if you really have to you can do this:

```
# LaserSprite.py
from Proj import PlayerShip

# Proj.py
def __import_laser():
    from LaserSprite import Laser
    return Laser

Laser = __import_laser()
```

These all should be top-level statements.